# Is there any way to control html pc and html mobile in a single component?

Tags: angular, testing, angular-cli, angular-test

I have the following code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { mobile } from '../../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'ctk-details-advisory',
  templateUrl: (mobile) ? 'details-advisory.component.mobile.html' : 
'details-advisory.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./details-advisory.component.scss'],
})
export class DetailsAdvisoryComponent implements OnInit {
// ...
```

this helps me control different html, pc and mobile view.
the problem is that when I want to perform unit tests I get the following error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' (mobile) ? 'details-advisory.component.mobile.html' : 'details-advisory.component.html'' in '/home/anonymous/criptoanalisis-0.2/frontend/src/app/pages/advisory/details-advisory'
>    @ ./src/app/pages/advisory/details-advisory/details-advisory.component.ts 23:22-121

would be of much help some solution to this problem
or another way to control different html
the truth is that I'm going a good time trying to solve the problem
I would greatly appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `html` (`details-advisory.component.html`), instead of using two different templates (one for mobile separately).
In the `component` code, define a class member

```
public isMobile = mobile; // imported from the environment in the import section
```

Then, in the `template` html code, you can use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isMobile; else desktopView">
// all html related to mobile view
</ng-container>

<ng-container #desktopview>
// all html related to desktop view
</ng-container>
```